# Laravel. Número de ocurrencias de clave foránea en seeders

Tags: php, laravel, relaciones, seeders

Tengo la siguiente relación academias-centros:

```
 Schema::create('academies', function(Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('centers')->unsigned()->nullable();   //number of centers
        $table->integer('academy_code')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });


 Schema::create('centers', function(Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('identification');
        $table->integer('academy_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Una academia tiene muchos centros y un centro pertenece a una academia. Pero en la relación tengo un campo en academias que es el número de centros que tiene la academia. Cómo puedo rellenar ese campo en los seeders con faker? Mi primera idea es rellenar con un número aleatorio pero es posible rellnarlo con datos exactos?

Mi seeder (con faker):

```
 $factory->define(App\Academy::class, function (Faker $faker) {
     return [
         'name' => $faker->name(),
         'identification' => $faker->ean8(),
         'centers' => // ?? number of occurences academy_id in centers table
         'academy_code' =>  rand(1,40),
     ];
 });
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Es un poco particular el diseño de tu base de datos, teniendo en cuenta que el dato del conteo lo puedes obtener con una simple consulta a la relación. Desde mi punto de vista considero innecesario ese campo en tu tabla. Si el problema es rendimiento (que lo dudo), puedes enviar al caché la consulta también.

Comment: @Shaz tienes toda la razón. COn una simple consulta se obtienen esos datos. Muchas gracias